# Multilevel multinomial logistic regression with mlogit (R)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multi-level, multinomial, multilevel-analysis

I´m trying to model a multilevel multinomial logistic regression.
I have 42 subjects with 82 observations per person. In each observation the suvjects("VP") were able to react in three different ways

```
mldata <- mlogit.data(data1, choice = "reaction.response", shape ="wide", 
alt.levels = c("reaction1","reaction2", "reaction3"), id.var 
="VP")
```

In oder to implement random predictors I tried this:

```
mod1<- mlogit(reaction.response ~ 1|TTC_ego_changer +TTC_changer_truck + 
HW_changer_truck +HW_ego_changer,
                         data = mldatalong, panel = TRUE,
                         rpar = c("reaction2:TTC_ego_changer" = "n", 
                        "reaction3:TTC_ego_changer" = "n" ), 
                          R = 500, halton = NA)
```

But how can I make the subjects ("VP") to level-2 units? The random slopes should varry over these 42 subjects.

Sorry for bad english and newbie behaviour :(